# CSS Pseudo Elements - Target Several Elements in a Single Parentheses Pair

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have an unordered list with several list points in an HTML.
In my CSS, I want to target the 5th and 7th list points. So I go

```
.my-list li:nth-child(5, 7){
background:yellow;
}
```

Nothing. It only works with a single number. So I assume I cannot separate them with a comma. What character/symbol should I separate them with? Is this even possible? Alternative solution? I doubt that I need to rewrite a target for every single *n*<sup>th</sup> element in my list... We're nearly in 2022. Just my reasoning.

Comment: *I doubt that I need to rewrite a target for every single nth element in my list.* --> you have to unless there is a pattern that we can express using A*n + B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your specific example, it’s somewhat easier to select the 5th and 7the elements than “*[rewriting the] the [selector] for every single *n*th element,*” using `:is()`:

```
.my-list li:is(:nth-child(5),:nth-child(7)) {
  background:yellow;
}
```

But it remains a somewhat verbose alternative, in contrast to the approach you desire, which is, as yet, not possible.

If JavaScript was an option, then a simple utility function could retrieve the desired elements, but not in CSS alone as yet.

Answer (score 1):

There is no symbol for that. You can separate them like this:

```
.my-list li:nth-child(5),
.my-list li:nth-child(7) {
    background: yellow;
}
```

If you use css-preprocessors you can write it a little bit cleaner, especially if you'll give class for list item:

```
.item {
    &:nth-child(5),
    &:nth-child(7) {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
}
```